# Cannot read SqlDataReader Object

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

Trying to get response from my azure db I am using the recommended [microsoft snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-dotnet-visual-studio)

```vb
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
sb.Append("select top 1 runname from vNameCode")
'sb.Append("where untgscod = ")
Dim sql As String = sb.ToString()
Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", reader.GetString(0), reader.GetString(1))
        End While
```

but as soon as I try to read the values I get the error:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

I get an object back but just cannot read it in the recommended way. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting `runname` from the table `vNameCode` but you are trying to access two values from the `reader`.

Do either of one changes:

1. Include the corresponding values in the `SELECT` statement.
2. Remove `reader.GetString()` from the `Console.WriteLine`

Try Below

```vb
Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
sb.Append("select top 1 runname from vNameCode")     
Dim sql As String = sb.ToString()
Using command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
    Using reader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", reader.GetString(0))
        End While
    End Using
End Using
```